# Aggregate SQL functions; AVG in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables. Student and test. I would like to make a query which gets the student name (firstname and lastname) of students who got higher than the average test_results.

My current query is wrong I think. Maybe its because I have not joined the two tables? This is my Query(in C#)

```
   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT student.studentFirstName, student.studentLastName, test.test_results FROM student, test WHERE test_results > (SELECT AVG(test_results) FROM test; ");
```

> you have an error in your SQL syntax

IF I have to join the 2 tables. I have a column named studentID in both tables

Comment: You don't have a join in your SQL statement. You have to join the two tables.

Comment: I thought so, I have a studentID in both tables

Comment: Learn a bit more about sql joins.

Comment: right, ok thank you

Comment: Can you share schema of both table used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to missing enclosing bracket. You should have enclosing bracket after `FROM test`.

But your query itself is wrong and need to make it correct. The correct query would be like :

```
SELECT student.studentFirstName, student.studentLastName, test.test_results 
FROM student, test 
WHERE student.studentID = test.studentID AND 
test_results > (SELECT AVG(test_results) FROM test);
```

If you would like to have solution with JOIN flavor, you can do like this :

```
SELECT student.studentFirstName, student.studentLastName, test.test_results 
FROM student INNER JOIN test ON student.id = test.id
WHERE test_results >( SELECT AVG(test.test_results) FROM test);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look on INNER/LEFT JOIN. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp